# Get the AccessTier of Blobs

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

I'm trying to get the **AccessTier** of blobs. I use the following code snippet:

```
var blobContainerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("container-name");

await foreach (var blobItem in blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync(BlobTraits.All, BlobStates.All))
{
     Console.WriteLine(blobItem.Properties.AccessTier)
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that AccessTier is always null. 
I've also tried to get properties explicitly, like:

```
var properties = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name).GetProperties().Value.AccessTier;
```

But still it's null. Is there a way to get **AccessTier** using Azure .NET SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the issue is my storage account's type is V1 and in V1 tiers are not supported.